# Install laravel passport in laravel vapor environment

Tags: laravel, oauth, laravel-passport, laravel-vapor

Installing [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport) worked for the local environment of [Laravel Vapor](https://vapor.laravel.com/). But after deploying it to production an error occured:

[image: Key path "file:///tmp/storage/oauth-private.key" does not exist or is not readable]

After searching the error message it seems that we need to run `php artisan passport:install` like mentioned [here](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/418).

**How can we do that with Laravel Vapor? Is there a way to get access to the server via `ssh`?**

Comment: You could try a [deploy-hook](https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/projects/deployments.html#deploy-hooks) to run `php artisan passport:keys` before the deployment is activated, the passport documentation mentions this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#deploying-passport).

Comment: Thanks for your response @Remul. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vapor doesn't have a permanent filesystem; each HTTP request hits a new Lambda instance.

The docs [have some info on deploying Passport keys](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#deploying-passport). On Vapor, your best bet is going to be using Vapor's "secrets" system to put them into the environment, then doing:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-config
```

> which will then provide the option to load the encryption keys from your environment variables:

You'll want to name your secrets `PASSPORT_PRIVATE_KEY` and `PASSPORT_PUBLIC_KEY` in Vapor.